# Why does querying on post_tags (which has been applied to custom post types) only return posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, taxonomy, tags

So I've created a little jquery cycle based feature rotator that pulls from the post_tags. I added the post tags to my other custom post types like this:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'reviews');
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'interviews');
//...
```

When I add a 'featured' tag to one of my reviews and one of my interviews, and query for it thusly:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_tag' => 'featured' ) );
```

I get two random posts instead of the two expected results.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a careful look at [the arguments for `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters).  By default, it queries for the post type `post`.

To select your custom post types, you need to change your query a little:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => array( 'reviews', 'interviews' ),
    'post_tag'  => 'featured' 
) );
```

Comment: Doh! it's always something simple isn't it? Thanks I have been banging my head against a wall!